# What could cause a Value Error in this short image matching function in Python (using numpy)?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy

I need a Python program I am working on to be able to find an exact, pixel for pixel match of a small image inside a larger one.  I have been using the following function, which is a slightly modified version of some code given in an answer to a question about how to do such image matching right here on Stack Overflow.  See here: [Determine if an image exists within a larger image, and if so, find it, using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663764/determine-if-an-image-exists-within-a-larger-image-and-if-so-find-it-using-py)

```
def find_image(im, tpl):
    '''finds an exact, pixel for pixel match of tpl inside im, or raises an 
    exception'''
    im = np.atleast_3d(im)
    tpl = np.atleast_3d(tpl)
    H, W, D = im.shape[:3]
    h, w = tpl.shape[:2]

    # Integral image and template sum per channel
    sat = im.cumsum(1).cumsum(0)
    tplsum = np.array([tpl[:, :, i].sum() for i in range(D)])

    # Calculate lookup table for all the possible windows
    iA, iB, iC, iD = sat[:-h, :-w], sat[:-h, w:], sat[h:, :-w], sat[h:, w:] 
    lookup = iD - iB - iC + iA
    # Possible matches
    possible_match = np.where(np.logical_and(*[lookup[..., i] == tplsum[i] for i in range(D)]))

    # Find exact match
    for y, x in zip(*possible_match):
        if np.all(im[y+1:y+h+1, x+1:x+w+1] == tpl):
            return (y+1, x+1)

    raise Exception("Image not found")
```

This has been working extremely well in most cases, but in one case, which happens to be very important, I got the following error.

`possible_match = np.where(np.logical_and(*[lookup[..., i] == tplsum[i] for i in range(D)]))`

`ValueError: invalid number of arguments`

I can't figure out what is causing this problem, or how to fix it.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The line causing the error is one comparison, a list comprehension and two function calls. I suggest you split it up and check every step individually. Wild guess from my side: the list comprehension 

     x for x in range(D)

is not recognized by np.logical_and as an array.

Comment: Another wild guess: `D != 2`: `np.logical_and` expects 2 arguments, so this only works if `D` is 2. Maybe the specific case that causes the problem is an image with different (unexpected) shape?

Answer (score 1):

The docs for `logical_and` specify `logical_and(x1, x2[, out])`. It expects 2 or 3 arguments.  You need to use `logical_and.reduce` if you want to compare anything other than 2 arrays.

For example:

```
    In [703]: A=np.ones((4,3),np.bool)

    In [704]: np.logical_and(*[a for a in A[:2,:]])
    Out[704]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

    In [705]: np.logical_and(*[a for a in A[:3,:]])
    Out[705]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

    In [706]: np.logical_and(*[a for a in A[:4,:]])
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-706-4ed655db12ce> in <module>()
    ----> 1 np.logical_and(*[a for a in A[:4,:]])

    ValueError: invalid number of arguments
```

`A[:1,:]` also produces this error (since it is only passing 1 argument).

```
In [707]: np.logical_and.reduce([a for a in A[:2,:]])
Out[707]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [708]: np.logical_and.reduce([a for a in A[:3,:]])
Out[708]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [709]: np.logical_and.reduce([a for a in A[:4,:]])
Out[709]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

It might be more instructive if my `A` wasn't all `True`.

I was puzzled why the `A[:3,:]` case ran, but then realized that the third array was being interpreted as the `out` argument.  It was setting `A[2,:]=np.logical_and(A[0,:],A[1,:])`.  Further evidence that `np.logical_and(*[...])` is not what you want.

An alternative that might work just as well is `np.all` over an axis:

```
np.all([a for a in A[:3,:]], axis=0)
```

I've just done some quick tests, so can't say for sure whether it's always the same, but it would worth checking (and may be timing).