# How to check existence of an image in other larger image file in python

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

I would like to check if specific image (small.png) is contained within another image file, big.png using python.

[image: big.png example]

Above is an example of big.png. And I have another file, small.png (just a crop of twitter icon) here:
[image: small.png]

I was wondering if there is a convenient way of chekcing for the existance of small.png in  big.png. (sort of like ahk.imagesearch function)
But it is not necessary to find the coordinate where the small.png is located in big.png. Thank you for your advice and help.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663764/determine-if-an-image-exists-within-a-larger-image-and-if-so-find-it-using-py

Comment: See template matching. But your solid blue small png will match many locations in both blue larger images. You generally do not want to try to match a solid patch in a larger image that has the same solid color. If all you want is to know if it matches anywhere, then the template matching will tell you that by the value of the match. See cv2.matchTemplate() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be